# How to evaluate a function within a formula expression (R)

Tags: r, function, formula, spline, gam

Suppose I want to write a function which can be used like the ordinary lm-type-functions: y~x...

Further I want that the function returns the full model.matrix of the input-variables which may have smooth terms as explanatory variables, i.e., an column of the input vector is first evaluated by a B-Spline-function and then returned.

So my little function looks like this:

```
model <- function(formula, data=list()){
mf <- model.frame(formula=formula, data=data)
return(mf)
}
```

The call should be able to evaluate smth. like

```
model(y~x1+spline(x2,5,1), data=dat)
```

where `spline(x2,5,1)` is the smooth influence of `x2`. My spline function is defined as this:

```
spline <- function(var,n,d){ 
    name <- deparse(substitute(var))
    Basis <- data.table(i=1:(n+d))
    Basis <- Basis[,B(i,d,var,knots(n,d,min(var),max(var))), by="i"]
    Basis[,numbers:=rep(1:length(var))]
    Basis <- as.data.table(dcast(Basis, numbers ~ i, value.var="V1"))
    Basis[,numbers:=NULL]
    setnames(Basis,names(Basis),paste0(name,".",1:(n+d)))
return(Basis)
}

B <- function(i,d,t,knots){
a <- (t - knots[i]) / ( knots[i+d] - knots[i] )
a <- ifelse(is.nan(a),0,a)
a <- ifelse(is.infinite(a),0,a)
b <- (knots[i+d+1] - t) / ( knots[i+d+1] - knots[i+1] )
b <- ifelse(is.nan(b),0,b)
b <- ifelse(is.infinite(b),0,b)
if(d==0)
    return( ifelse(t>=knots[i] & t < knots[i+1],1,0) )
else
    return( a*B(i,d-1,t,knots)+b*B(i+1,d-1,t,knots) )
}


knots <- function(m,d,min,max){
    k <- seq(min,max,length.out=m+1)
    step <- k[2]-k[1]
    outer.l <- rev(min(k)-step*(1:d))
    outer.r <- max(k)+step*(1:d)
    return(c(outer.l,k,outer.r))
}
```

If I call the fucntion `model` it is not able to evaluate `spline(x2,5,1)` since data-argument does not contain the corresponding column.

I looked at `gam` but here a hole new function `interpret.gam` is used to do this. Is there not an easier way?

Comment: I did not activate the self-answer option but here the solution if someone encounters such a problem: The object which is return by my spline function was not a matrix. If it is converted as such everything works as intended.